# Multiple windows with an image in each

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm currently working on a safe virus that just spams windows with an image on it, but I ran into a problem of not able to have the image on multiple windows

This is my current code:

```py
from tkinter import Tk, mainloop, Label
from random import randint
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

def Spawn(self):
    self.win = Tk()
    self.win.geometry(str(randint(10,1000))+'x'+str(randint(10,1000))+'+'+str(randint(-20,800))+'+'+str(randint(-20,500)))
    self.win.label = Label(self.win, image= ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(r"bean.jpg"))).pack()
    self.win.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.MULTIPLY)
    
class ULTRASUS():
    def __init__(self):
        Spawn(self)
        
    def MULTIPLY(self):
        self.win.destroy()
        Spawn(self)

for I in range (25): ULTRASUS()
    
mainloop()
```

Comment: Don't create more than one instance of `Tk`. Instead, after the root window, create instances of `Toplevel`.

Comment: the class does not appear to be correctly constructed....   did you mean to put `def Spawn(self):` as a function, class or method of the `ULTRASUS` class ?

Comment: ...remember that python is very forgiving in the sense that it will let the user write poorly formed code without throwing errors like strongly typed languages !

Comment: You also need to keep a reference to the PhotoImage object, or it will be garbage-collected.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424091/why-does-tkinter-image-not-show-up-if-created-in-a-function is the general solution, but since you're using only one image, it might as well be a global variable (loaded once, rather than once per window), in which case the problem doesn't arise.

Comment: I'm relatively news to tkinter so I have no idea what you guys meant (sorry), it would be great if someone could help me with a basic structure for it. I did research but I doesn't understand any

Comment: All you need are already given by the above comments. I'll recap. Change the ```Tk()``` to the ```Toplevel()``` and store the return value of the ```ImageTk.PhotoImage()``` as an instance(member) variable. Of course, you should create a single Tk() root window at the beginning.

Comment: YOOOO! Thx you guys a lot! I couldn't do it without help from you guys! :smile: